# Android Prompting an AlertDialog onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to finish up my main menu in my application. I thought it would be a simple nice touch to add an AlertDialog in the OnBackPressed method. However for some reason I am getting all kinds of errors.

I created the AlertDialog in the OnBackPressed and show it but the app just closes when I press the back button and I get errors saying that the window is leaking.

Any idea how to fix this? I searched for about 30 minutes and couldn't find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Show the code for `onBackPressed()`...although I'm not sure that what you're trying to do is a good idea.

Comment: AlertDialogs that display when the back button is pressed (i.e. "confirm exit" dialogs) ***severely*** slow down the user experience. I've done it before and was very surprised at how much faster my app appeared to be when I removed them in a subsequent version. Don't use them unless you really, *really*, ***really*** need to :).

Comment: @AlexLockwood would you say, that I really, really, **really** need to show an alert dialog if otherwise the changes a user made would be lost by simple going back?

Answer (score 40):

Try to not call **super.OnBackPressed()**, this code shoul help:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to call super.onBackPressed() use this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //finish();
                    MyActivity.this.onSuperBackPressed();
                    //super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    /*
    if (handleCancel()){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    */
}

public void onSuperBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I just added a new public method `onSuperBackPressed` with the `super`-method to MyActivity.

Thanks goes to [K_Anas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327899/k-anas) for providing the excellent idea.

Answer (score 5):

> I created the AlertDialog in the OnBackPressed and show it but the app just closes when I press the back button and I get errors saying that the window is leaking.

If inside your `OnBackPressed` you are calling `super.OnBackPressed()` then the application will finish, as that's what the base implementation of `OnBackPressed` does. Don't call the `super` method, and the application won't close.

Answer (score 0):

call yourActivity.this.onBackPressed() in your dialog

```
utility.makeAlertDialog("Cancel Verification","Do you want to cancel the verification process","Cancel Verification",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            utility.failureToast("OTP verification");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MobileOTPActivity.this,MobileNumberLoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            MobileOTPActivity.this.onBackPressed();
        }
    },"Close");
```